# In IOS hide input field blinking cursor for CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

How to hide ios input field blinking cursor. am trying so many ways it's not working for me.

In Windows,

**SCSS**

```
.input--textfield {
    border: none;
    color: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 gray;
    
    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="" value="10" class="input--textfield">
```

Working for me,

**IOS**

Not working below code, do you have any suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

Try below it's very simple and working for me in IOS (5s, 6), IOS desktop and windows.

```css
.input--textfield { caret-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" value="10" class="input--textfield">
```

Answer (score 1):

ios android

```
.input--textfield {
  border: none;
  color: transparent;
  caret-color: transparent;
  text-indent: -999em;
}
<input type="text" name="" value="10" class="input--textfield">
```